# React JS/Firebase/React bootstrap table - Why am I getting an error when deleting an entry other than the last one?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-bootstrap-table

so I'm having issues re-rendering my firebase db after removing an entry other than the last one. It removes just fine from firebase, but when it re-renders the react bootstrap table it throws the TypeError. Below is the error and my firebase structure. Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm approaching this? I was thinking maybe if I updated the parent "id" of the bugs with an iteration of the length it might fix it, but I'm having trouble with updating the parent. 
**Picture of tablebody.js code is not my code, it was written with the react-bootstrap-table. This section is where the error points to though.**

[image]

[image: Here is what my structure looks like]
[image]

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import withAuthorization from './withAuthorization';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import './reactTable.css';

const Header = () =>
    <div>
        <PageHeader>Create a Bug/Issue</PageHeader>
    </div>

const db = firebase.database().ref('bugs/');

class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.stationBug = this.stationBug.bind(this);
        this.issueBug = this.issueBug.bind(this);
        this.descBug = this.descBug.bind(this);
        this.submitBug = this.submitBug.bind(this);
        this.removeBug = this.removeBug.bind(this);
    this.updateBug = this.updateBug.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleAssign = this.handleAssign.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            length: '',
            station: '',
            bug: '',
            desc: '',
            value: 'low',
            assign: 'admin',
            bugs: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        db.on ('value', (snapshot) => {
            const currentBugs = snapshot.val()
            if (currentBugs != null) {
                this.setState({
                    bugs: currentBugs
                })
            }
        })
    }

    stationBug(event) {
        this.setState({station: event.target.value});
    }

    issueBug(event) {
        this.setState({bug: event.target.value});
    }

    descBug(event) {
        this.setState({desc: event.target.value});
    }

    submitBug(event) {
        const nextBug = {
            id: this.state.bugs.length,
            station: this.state.station,
            bug: this.state.bug,
            desc: this.state.desc,
            priority: this.state.value,
            assign: this.state.assign
        }
        firebase.database().ref('bugs/'+nextBug.id).set(nextBug);
    }

    removeBug(event) {
        const idNum = this.state.station;
        db.child(idNum).remove();
        /*
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.bugs.length; i++) {
            this.state.bugs['/id'] = i;
            db.update(i);
        };*/
    }

  updateBug(event) {
        const idNum = this.state.station;
        const descUpdate = this.state.desc;
        var updates = {};
        updates['/desc'] = descUpdate;
        db.child(idNum).update(updates);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleAssign(event) {
    this.setState({assign: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <BootstrapTable
                ref='table'
                data={ this.state.bugs }
                pagination={ true }
                search={ true }
                hover={ true }>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey={true} width="10">Ref ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='station' width="10" dataSort={true}>Station</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='bug' width="25">Bug/Issue</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='desc' width="50">Description</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='priority' width="50">Priority</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='assign' width="50">Assigned To</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>

            <input onChange={this.stationBug} type="text" placeholder="Station #" />
            <br />
            <textarea onChange={this.issueBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug/Issue" />
            <br />
            <textarea onChange={this.descBug} type="text" placeholder="Bug Description" />
            <br />
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="high">High</option>
          <option value="medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="low">Low</option>
                </select>
            <br />
        <select value={this.state.assign} onChange={this.handleAssign}>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
          <option value="bob">Bob</option>
                </select>
            <br />
            <Button bsSize="large" onClick={this.submitBug} type="submit"> Enter Bug </Button>
            <Button bsSize="large" onClick={this.removeBug} type="submit"> Remove Bug </Button>
      <Button bsSize="large" onClick={this.updateBug} type="submit"> Update Bug </Button>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(HomePage);
//export default HomePage;
```

Comment: It might help to share the code in `TableBody.js`

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that there is a newer version of bootstrap table, react-bootstrap-table-next (react bootstrap table2) converting to that fixed the issue of it not rerendering. I just need to determine a better unique id rather than array length for when I delete bugs. https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/table-props.html